# NoSQL, ElasticSearch or even old school relational database?

Tags: elasticsearch, db2, nosql

we have an application that stores records of events in a DB2 database. And we have users that query these events, based on the time of the events, and optional some ids as search criteria.

- The data is only once written, no updates on these records.
- The query has no joins an selects only the entries from this one table
- about 1 million of entries per day
- The event data structure is always the same, but there is a content field, that could by only a short string or a very big string (3500), or optional a clob field if the string content filed is to short

Currently this concept works, but the queries are not very fast. In the future the incoming events will increase.
So we are currently thinking about our solution, if a relational database is the right solution for our usecase or can a NoSQL solution better fit our requierements.

After some research about the different NoSQL solutions (column based, key-value, ...), we have no idea if one of this fit. We have also seen ElasticSearch as an alternative, but don't know which storage ElasticSearch uses.

So, have you any ideas what to do, or in which direction our research should go, to fit this usecase.

Regards,
mananana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you say it isn't clear if you attempted to tune your existing database. If you did not, it is usually much more efficient (time- and effort-wise) to tune an existing solution rather than move all your data to a new platform (which will still require tuning). Only after clearly exhausting all tuning options should you consider migration.

Comment: Yes, that's true. And we allready have found a few optimizations we could do in our current solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you my experience. A few months ago we were having similar problems. We were using a mssql db and were looking into changing to a nosql solution.

I investigated a lot of dbs and eventually decided on elastic search because of its amazing search speed and power.

It was super easy to setup. Even setting up a cluster is a breeze. It uses lucene in the background for searches.

We have not had any major issues since we made the switch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Which database uses ElasticSearch? Or is ElasticSearch the database?

Comment: ElasticSearch is the database. Its a document store.

Comment: An event would therefore be a document and each entry in the document store would then be an event. @mananana

Answer (score 0):

"Queries are not very fast" seems vague. Optimisation of the existing solution may be the cheapest and fastest option, even if it means some change to the existing database. Investigate the cause of the slow queries. Is the table range-partitioned per day, or per week or other interval, and if not then why not?  Is the table using row-compression?  Are there suitable indexes for the most common predicates and are they being used?